# How Do I add New ethernet device to Kernel Config file

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

[image]I wanted to add a new device for Kernel compiled for vexpress board.I would want to see new device option should come under meuconfig program.

```
make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig 

make ARCH=arm menuconfig
```

I would want to see TI device support under --Ethernet Driver Support under  menuconfig.

Also doing so would allow me to compile .o files related TI driver code provided in Linux kernel?

[image]

EDIT: I have added two snapshots of vexpress menuconfig and Keystone menuconfig,I would want to have support for TI devices in vexpress meuconfig which is second snapshot here.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit file: .../drivers/net/Kconfig and add there your entry for enabling TI device:

```
config TI_ETHER_NET
    tristate "TI Ethernet support"
    depends on PCI
    help
      This is my driver for TI device
```

and then copy your drivers source into .../drivers/net/ and add appropriate entry to Makefile in this directory:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_TI_ETHER_NET) += your_driver.o
```

Comment: Thanks ,Source is already present in drivers/net/ethernet/ti ,so is there anything need to be done differently now?

Comment: just edit Kconfig and Makefile files as I wrote earlier

Comment: Sorry - you have to changes paths: in drivers/net/ethernet/ti you need to have Makefile for your driver of course. In drivers/net/Makefile you need to add such entry:     obj-$(CONFIG_TI_ETHER_NET) += ethernet/ti/ to let Makefile find your drivers path.

Comment: I am just bit confused now,Do I have to only add  obj-$(CONFIG_TI_ETHER_NET) += ethernet/ti/ to the drivers/net/Makefile or there needs to be done more?

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar You'll have to do a make menuconfig to get your top level .config file updated and then make the kernel.  Check to see that your_driver.c got compiled and linked in.